# Using timers - how to?

Tags: java, android

I got a problem with timer. After 2 sec instead of this action I am getting an error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        Timer timer=new Timer();

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("why?");
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(timerTask,2000);
    }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Just error in app: "Programm has stopped"

Comment: You should give us the error you are getting on ADB. If you are using Android Studio, simply find the error in your monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run these from non main thread

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv.setText("why?");
        }
```

You have to use runOnUiThread

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     tv.setText("why?");
                }});
           }
    }
```

Or use post method of View like

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
           tv.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     tv.setText("why?");
                }});
           }
    }
```

I know it looks like weird, but if you write it using lambdas its much better and concise

```
timer.schedule(()->{tv.post(()->{setText("why?");}},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update UI from inside a thread. Update UI from main thread.

Create a handler and send message to the handler after your work has been completed and update the UIthere.

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        // Update UI
    }
};
```

and send message to handler using `handler.sendMessage()`